# Printer keeps pausing and restart during print process

Tags: marlin, prusaslicer

I'm using `Marlin bugfix 2.0.x` with my custom printer. Sliced a test cube with `PrusaSlicer 2.2.0`.

My printer starts printing process but randomly stops for one second and then continues.

Where I can start to find what's wrong?

Comment: Help-us-help-you! What printer? What's your settings? We need to know more!

Comment: Some versions of Cura had a bug that caused speed of light to be written into the gcode where there was a missing speed limit, and that overflowed the Marlin firmware and turned into an extremely slow move (behaving like a pause). Maybe PrusaSlicer had the same bug. Look in the gcode file where the pause is happening for odd feedrates.

Comment: Mine is a custom printer based on RAMPS 1.4. I updated Marlin firmware to `bugfix-2.0.x` and it seems it starts to pausing just a second during print process. I'll check the gcode file asap.